# Can I use a Google credential json file for authentication in a Dataflow job?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I want to use a credential json file (or string) to authenticate a Beam job to read from a GCS bucket.
Notably, the credentials are provided by a user (in an existing process so I'm stuck using the json file rather than a service account in my own GCP project).

### What I've tried

- Using `fsspec`/`gcsfs`: this seems to work, but I'm worried about scalability and I assume Beam's file io is more optimized to scale and plays nicer with Beam objects
- Creating my own "storage_client" to pass to `apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO`, trying to go off [these docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio.html). The storage client seems to be Beam's own internal client:

  - I've tried passing a `google.cloud.storage.Client` for this, and the client listed in the docs is deprecated with lots of things written in red on the repo, so I'd like to avoid using it.
  - I've tried passing `google.auth` credentials to it in a few different forms: the raw dict (read by parsing the json), `google.auth.load_credentials_from_file`-based creds, and [impersonated credentials](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.impersonated_credentials.html)
- Creating `from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.GoogleCloudOptions` to pass to a `apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem.GCSFileSystem`. I found [these docs from beam](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem.html) and [these docs from google](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/pipeline-options), but I haven't been able to piece together how to pass *json credentials* for authentication.
- I've dabbled in the idea of using [Google KMS](https://cloud.google.com/security-key-management) for passing the creds securely, but (as far as I can tell) it doesn't solve my problem for getting Beam to use the credentials.

### Small-ish Example

It'd be nice to get something like this working:

```
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions, PipelineOptions
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio import GcsIO
from apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem import GCSFileSystem

# need to support "type": "service_account", but would be nice to be able to support "type": "authorized_user" too, if possible
cred_file = "/path/to/file.json"

# not sure which of these is preferable for this...
options = PipelineOptions()
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
    
# voodoo

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    gcs = GcsIO()
    gcs.open("gs://path/to/file.txt")

    # or
    gcs = GCSFileSystem(options)
    gcs.open("gs://path/to/file.txt")
```

Happy to provide any other info that could help, as you can see I've been at this for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

You can add service account credentials to your code as below.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

key_path = "path/to/service_account.json"  
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],)
```

Comment: So I know how to read the credentials in, but how to I get beam to use those credentials when reading in files?

Comment: Does this [link](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.4.0/_modules/apache_beam/internal/gcp/auth.html) help you? You can refer to this [document](https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-beam-pipeline-for-cleaning-batch-data-using-cloud-dataflow-and-bigquery-f9272cd89eba) to read data from GCS bucket using Apache beam.

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT do you have a similar method when using ADC-generated credentials (so not type `service_account`) by running `gcloud application-default login`, which are of type `authorized_user` (refresh token)?